# after form validation selecting option is not working properly

Tags: codeigniter

Please help me I am facing this problem when I click on submit button and my form rout to validation so after validation select option not working properly I used ajax for selecting option is there any buddy here to help me

It does not working after this validation when I remove it so its working

```
public function validate()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('sub_ctg', 'sub_ctg|callback_select_validate'); 
}
```